ClassCastException in Spark 3.4.1 during Dataset reduce operation
I'm encountering a runtime error related to type casting after upgrading Apache Spark from version 3.2.1 to 3.4.1. This error didn't occur in the previous version. Specifically, a java.lang.ClassCastException is thrown when using Dataset.reduce() on a custom case class. Here's a simplified version of the code that reproduces the issue:
case class CustomCaseClass(id: String, body: Map[String, Int])

val result = someDataset
  .groupByKey(ds => ds.id)(Encoders.STRING)
  .mapGroups((key, iter) => CustomCaseClass(key, Map(key -> iter.length)))(Encoders.product)
  .reduce((before, next) => before.copy(body = before.body ++ next.body))

When executing this code, I get the following error:
class threw exception: java.lang.ClassCastException: CustomCaseClass cannot be cast to CustomCaseClass

This error is puzzling because it's trying to cast CustomCaseClass to itself.
I've tried the following approaches, but the issue persists:
Using explicit encoders
Disabling AQE (Adaptive Query Execution)
Questions:
What could be causing this ClassCastException in Spark 3.4.1?
Are there any specific serializer options I should modify?
Should I use a more precise Encoder instead of Encoders.product? If
so, how?
Are there any known issues or changes in Spark 3.4.1 that might be causing this?
What should I fix for resolve this error?
Any insights or solutions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!
Environment:
Spark version: 3.4.1
Scala version: 2.12.17
Jvm : 1.8.0.341

Can you show the complete error stack trace? What's the type of someDataset? Any chance you have multiple classes with this name in different JARs / packages in your class path?

Hi @Gaël J. someDataset is also a user-defined case class type. And there are no other classes with the same name

Could you please take a look? @GaëlJ

@GaëlJ
Complete stack is too long to leave. here's part of stack
[2024-09-08, 08:42:47 UTC] {orca.py:276} INFO - Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.msf.service.reconciliation.dto.HiveReconciliationDto cannot be cast to com.msf.service.reconciliation.dto.HiveReconciliationDto
[2024-09-08, 08:42:47 UTC] {orca.py:276} INFO - at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$reduce$3(RDD.scala:1104)
[2024-09-08, 08:42:47 UTC] {orca.py:276} INFO - at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$reduce$3$adapted(RDD.scala:1101)
